# MySQL in PHP; strange behavior with my script

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have been having troubles with my database project. I'm using XAMPP (3.2.1 [Compiled: May 7th 2013]) and run database on localhost with phpMyAdmin. I have 64-bit Windows 8.1 running on ASUS X555L (if that's helpful info).

I wrote a php script to load the database, but have been having troubles. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head><title>Load KTCS Database</title></head>
<body>

<?php
/* Program: KTCS_load.php
 * Desc:    Creates and loads the KTCS database tables with 
 *          sample data.
 */

 $host = "localhost";
 $user = "11cph2";
 $password = "samplePassword";
 $database = "ktcs";

 $cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password, $database);
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  die();
  }

   mysqli_query($cxn,"drop table Car;");
   mysqli_query($cxn,"drop table Member;");
   mysqli_query($cxn,"drop table old_member;");
   mysqli_query($cxn,"drop table Reservations;");
   mysqli_query($cxn,"drop table Pick_Up;");
   mysqli_query($cxn,"drop table Rental_History;");
   mysqli_query($cxn,"drop table Locations;");
   mysqli_query($cxn,"drop table Fee;");
   mysqli_query($cxn,"drop table Comment;");
   mysqli_query($cxn,"drop table Reply;");
   mysqli_query($cxn,"drop table Administrator;");
   mysqli_query($cxn,"drop table Member_Password;");
   mysqli_query($cxn,"drop table Admin_Password;");

   mysqli_query($cxn,"CREATE TABLE Car(
                  VIN               CHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
                  make              VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
                  model             VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
                  year              CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
                  type              CHAR(3)         NOT NULL,
                  LAddress          VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
                  status            CHAR(20)        NOT NULL,
                  LastOMRead        CHAR(6),        
                  LastGasRead       CHAR(2),        
                  LastMaintOMRead   CHAR(6),        
                  LastMaintGasRead  CHAR(2),                
                  PRIMARY KEY(VIN));");

   mysqli_query($cxn,"CREATE TABLE Member(
                  MNo               CHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
                  MName             VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
                  MAddress          VARCHAR(60)     NOT NULL,
                  MPhoneNo          CHAR(10),       
                  MEmail            VARCHAR(30),        
                  DLicenseNo        CHAR(15)        NOT NULL,
                  CCardNo           CHAR(16)        NOT NULL,   
                  CCardExpDate      CHAR(5)         NOT NULL,
                  RegAnnivDate      DATE            NOT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY(MNo));");

    mysqli_query($cxn,"CREATE TABLE old_member(
                  MNo               CHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
                  MName             VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
                  MAddress          VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
                  MPhoneNo          CHAR(11),       
                  MEmail                VARCHAR(30),
                  PRIMARY KEY(MNo));");

   mysqli_query($cxn,"CREATE TABLE Reservations(
                  ResNo         CHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
                  MNo           CHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
                  VIN           CHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
                  ResDate       DATE        NOT NULL,
                  ResTime   CHAR(5)     NOT NULL,
                  PickUpAddress     VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY(ResNo),
                  FOREIGN KEY (MNo) REFERENCES Member(MNo),
                  FOREIGN KEY (VIN) REFERENCES Car (VIN));");

     mysqli_query($cxn,"CREATE TABLE pick_up(
                  ResNo         CHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
                  MNo           CHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
                  VIN           CHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
                  ResDate       DATE            NOT NULL,
                  ResTime   CHAR(5)             NOT NULL,
                  PickUpDate    DATE            NOT NULL,
                  PickUpTime    CHAR(5)         NOT NULL,
                  PickUpAddress     VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
                  PUpOMRead     CHAR(6)         NOT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY(ResNo),
                  FOREIGN KEY (MNo) REFERENCES Member(MNo),
                  FOREIGN KEY (VIN) REFERENCES Car (VIN));");

     mysqli_query($cxn,"CREATE TABLE Rental_History(
                  ResNo         CHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
                  MNo           CHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
                  VIN           CHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
                  PickUpDate    DATE        NOT NULL,
                  PickUpTime    CHAR(5)     NOT NULL,
                  ReturnDate    DATE        NOT NULL,
                  ReturnTime    CHAR(5)     NOT NULL,
                  PickUpAddress VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
                  RetAddress    VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
                  PUpOMRead     CHAR(6)     NOT NULL,
                  RetOMRead     CHAR(6)     NOT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY(ResNo),
                  FOREIGN KEY (MNo) REFERENCES Member(MNo),
                  FOREIGN KEY (VIN) REFERENCES Car (VIN));");

   mysqli_query($cxn,"CREATE TABLE Locations(
                  LAddress          VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
                  NoAvailSpaces     INTEGER         NOT NULL,   
                  PRIMARY KEY(LAddress));");

   mysqli_query($cxn,"CREATE TABLE Fee(
                  MNo           CHAR(10)            NOT NULL,
                  AnnualMemFee  DECIMAL(5,2)        NOT NULL,
                  UsageFee      DECIMAL(5,2),       
                  PRIMARY KEY (MNo),
                  FOREIGN KEY (MNo) REFERENCES Member(MNo));");

    mysqli_query($cxn,"CREATE TABLE Comment(
                  MNo           CHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
                  Date          DATE            NOT NULL,
                  Time          CHAR(5)         NOT NULL,
                  Topic         CHAR(7)         NOT NULL,
                  Comment       VARCHAR(300)    NOT NULL,
                  Reply         VARCHAR(300)    NOT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY(MNo, Date, Time),
                  FOREIGN KEY (MNo) REFERENCES Member(MNo));");

    mysqli_query($cxn,"CREATE TABLE Reply(
                  ENo           CHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
                  ReplyDate     DATE            NOT NULL,
                  ReplyTime     CHAR(5)         NOT NULL,
                  MNo           CHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
                  Date          DATE            NOT NULL,
                  Time          CHAR(5)         NOT NULL,
                  Reply         VARCHAR(300)    NOT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY(ENo, ReplyDate, ReplyTime, MNo, Date, Time),
                  FOREIGN KEY (MNo) REFERENCES Member(MNo),
                  FOREIGN KEY (ENo) REFERENCES Administrator(ENo));");

    mysqli_query($cxn,"CREATE TABLE Administrator(
                  ENo           CHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
                  EName         VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
                  EAddress      VARCHAR(60)     NOT NULL,
                  EPhoneNo      CHAR(10)        NOT NULL,       
                  EEmail        VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,       
                  SIN           CHAR(9)     NOT NULL,
                  Salary        INTEGER         NOT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY(ENo));");           

    mysqli_query($cxn,"CREATE TABLE Member_Password(
                  MNo           CHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
                  MPassword     VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY(MNo),
                  FOREIGN KEY (MNo) REFERENCES Member(MNo));");           

    mysqli_query($cxn,"CREATE TABLE Admin_Password(
                  ENo           CHAR(10)        NOT NULL,
                  EPassword     VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY(ENo),
                  FOREIGN KEY (ENo) REFERENCES Administrator(ENo));");

   mysqli_query($cxn,"insert into Car values
         ('0000000050', 'Toyota',   'Corolla',      'Car',  '2003', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'in-use',               '2015007',  '54','185064', '66'),
         ('0000000051', 'Toyota',   'Corolla',      'Car',  '2003', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'in-use',               '2015007',  '54','185064', '66'),
         ('0000000052', 'Toyota',   'Corolla',      'Car',  '2003', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'available',            '2015007',  '54','185064', '66'),
         ('0000000053', 'Toyota',   'Corolla',      'Car',  '2003', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'out-for-maintenance',  '2015007',  '54','185064', '66'),
         ('0000000054', 'Toyota',   'Corolla',      'Car',  '2003', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'in-use',               '2015007',  '54','185064', '66'),
         ('0000000055', 'Toyota',   'Corolla',      'Car',  '2003', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'available',            '2015007',  '54','185064', '66'),
         ('0000000056', 'Toyota',   'Corolla',      'Car',  '2003', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'in-use',               '2015007',  '54','185064', '66'),
         ('0000000057', 'Toyota',   'Corolla',      'Car',  '2003', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'out-for-maintenance',  '2015007',  '54','185064', '66'),
         ('0000000058', 'Toyota',   'Corolla',      'Car',  '2003', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'in-use',               '2015007',  '54','185064', '66'),
         ('0000000059', 'Toyota',   'Corolla',      'Car',  '2003', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'in-use',               '2015007',  '54','185064', '66'),
         ('0000000010', 'Hyundai',  'Accent Sedan', 'Van',  '2007', '427 king Street, Kingston, ON',        'available',            '079430',   '33','022542', '27'),
         ('0000000011', 'Hyundai',  'Accent Sedan', 'Van',  '2007', '427 king Street, Kingston, ON',        'available',            '079430',   '33','022542', '27'),
         ('0000000012', 'Hyundai',  'Accent Sedan', 'Van',  '2007', '427 king Street, Kingston, ON',        'out-for-maintenance',  '079430',   '33','022542', '27'),
         ('0000000013', 'Hyundai',  'Accent Sedan', 'Van',  '2007', '427 king Street, Kingston, ON',        'available',            '079430',   '33','022542', '27'),
         ('0000000014', 'Hyundai',  'Accent Sedan', 'Van',  '2007', '427 king Street, Kingston, ON',        'out-for-maintenance',  '079430',   '33','022542', '27'),
         ('0000000015', 'Hyundai',  'Accent Sedan', 'Van',  '2007', '427 king Street, Kingston, ON',        'available',            '079430',   '33','022542', '27'),
         ('0000000016', 'Hyundai',  'Accent Sedan', 'Van',  '2007', '427 king Street, Kingston, ON',        'available',            '079430',   '33','022542', '27'),
         ('0000000017', 'Hyundai',  'Accent Sedan', 'Van',  '2007', '427 king Street, Kingston, ON',        'in-use',               '079430',   '33','022542', '27'),
         ('0000000018', 'Hyundai',  'Accent Sedan', 'Van',  '2007', '427 king Street, Kingston, ON',        'in-use',               '079430',   '33','022542', '27'),
         ('0000000019', 'Hyundai',  'Accent Sedan', 'Van',  '2007', '427 king Street, Kingston, ON',        'available',            '079430',   '33','022542', '27'),
         ('0000000060', 'KIA',      'Sorento',      'Van',  '2004', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'in-use',               '071900',   '12','065405', '50'),
         ('0000000061', 'KIA',      'Sorento',      'Van',  '2004', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'available',            '071900',   '12','065405', '50'),
         ('0000000062', 'KIA',      'Sorento',      'Van',  '2004', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'in-use',               '071900',   '12','065405', '50'),
         ('0000000063', 'KIA',      'Sorento',      'Van',  '2004', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'in-use',               '071900',   '12','065405', '50'),
         ('0000000064', 'KIA',      'Sorento',      'Van',  '2004', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'out-for-maintenance',  '071900',   '12','065405', '50'),
         ('0000000065', 'KIA',      'Sorento',      'Van',  '2004', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'in-use',               '071900',   '12','065405', '50'),
         ('0000000066', 'KIA',      'Sorento',      'Van',  '2004', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'available',            '071900',   '12','065405', '50'),
         ('0000000067', 'KIA',      'Sorento',      'Van',  '2004', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'in-use',               '071900',   '12','065405', '50'),
         ('0000000068', 'KIA',      'Sorento',      'Van',  '2004', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'in-use',               '071900',   '12','065405', '50'),
         ('0000000069', 'KIA',      'Sorento',      'Van',  '2004', '240 Princess Street, Kingston',        'available',            '071900',   '12','065405', '50'),
         ('0000000030', 'Honda',    'Civic',        'Car',  '2004', '746 Gardiners Road, Kingston, ON',     'out-for-maintenance',  '160547',   '27','120548', '38'),
         ('0000000031', 'Honda',    'Civic',        'Car',  '2004', '746 Gardiners Road, Kingston, ON',     'available',            '160547',   '27','120548', '38'),
         ('0000000032', 'Honda',    'Civic',        'Car',  '2004', '746 Gardiners Road, Kingston, ON',     'available',            '160547',   '27','120548', '38'),
         ('0000000033', 'Honda',    'Civic',        'Car',  '2004', '746 Gardiners Road, Kingston, ON',     'in-use',               '160547',   '27','120548', '38'),
         ('0000000034', 'Honda',    'Civic',        'Car',  '2004', '746 Gardiners Road, Kingston, ON',     'available',            '160547',   '27','120548', '38'),
         ('0000000035', 'Honda',    'Civic',        'Car',  '2004', '746 Gardiners Road, Kingston, ON',     'available',            '160547',   '27','120548', '38'),
         ('0000000036', 'Honda',    'Civic',        'Car',  '2004', '746 Gardiners Road, Kingston, ON',     'in-use',               '160547',   '27','120548', '38'),
         ('0000000037', 'Honda',    'Civic',        'Car',  '2004', '746 Gardiners Road, Kingston, ON',     'in-use',               '160547',   '27','120548', '38'),
         ('0000000038', 'Honda',    'Civic',        'Car',  '2004', '746 Gardiners Road, Kingston, ON',     'available',            '160547',   '27','120548', '38'),
         ('0000000039', 'Honda',    'Civic',        'Car',  '2004', '746 Gardiners Road, Kingston, ON',     'available',            '160547',   '27','120548', '38');");



  mysqli_query($cxn,"insert into Member values
         ('0000000001', 'Johnny Graph', '25 Collingwood Street, Kingston, ON',  null,           null,                       'H1479681425432',   '4560792363707025', '12/15', '2015-06-12'),
         ('0000000002', 'Brian Moore',  '246 Albert Street, Kingston, ON',      '6134829215',   'brianmoorecsqueensuca',    'F61374545461262',  '3460602855077016', '03/17', '2015-10-06'),
         ('0000000003', 'Aaron Abbey',  '38 Sydenham Street, Kingston, ON',     null,           null,                       'E94384541504362',  '7148061363696900', '09/18', '2015-03-27'),
         ('0000000004', 'Annie Wang',   '1060 Woodbine Road, Kingston, ON',     '6135579438',   null,                       'H14682024658751',  '4590286617636329', '01/16', '2016-01-19');");



   mysqli_query($cxn,"insert into Reservations values
         ('0000000020', '0000000001', '0000000037', '2015-06-10', '11:00', '240 Princess Street, Kingston, ON'),
         ('0000000068', '0000000002', '0000000050', '2015-04-05', '10:30', '185 Bath Road, Kingston, ON'),
         ('0000000076', '0000000001', '0000000036', '2015-04-09', '09:30', '427 king Street, Kingston, ON'),
         ('0000000098', '0000000004', '0000000057', '2015-05-14', '10:00', '240 Princess Street, Kingston, ON'),
         ('0000000104', '0000000004', '0000000013', '2015-08-23', '17:00', '185 Bath Road, Kingston, ON'),
         ('0000000130', '0000000001', '0000000065', '2015-07-06', '12:30', '240 Princess Street, Kingston, ON'),
         ('0000000147', '0000000003', '0000000055', '2015-04-17', '15:00', '240 Princess Street, Kingston, ON');");

   mysqli_close($cxn); 

echo "KTCS database created.";

?>
</body></html>
```

Here's a link to my ER Diagram. Sorry if there are a lot of things that I miss or logically wrong.. I'm pretty new to it.

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDGbR.png)

Here are a list of my problems:

1. I have troubles adding values to the table sometimes.
2. When I comment out all the "create table" and "add value" code (aka only "drop table" left), I cannot drop the tables all at once (need to run the script twice). Can it be the foreign key constraints?
3. When I have the whole database empty (no tables) and only include the "drop table" and "create table" code, not all tables are added to the database at once. The table "Reply" is added only if I run the script the second time. Why is that?

Right now I have all the values successfully added to the database, but before I go on further I just want to clear out all these strange behavior of my program. I don't know what's causing it, but possibly something to do with foreign key.

It is really frustrating with the inconsistent behavior because I spent a long time checking for data types and syntax errors. A lot of times the syntax is perfect, but I just had to run the script a few more times for the table to show up, or drop all the tables before I try to load the tables.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

for drop and create table better use this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXIST
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST
```

Comment: I tried
`DROP TABLE IF EXIST table_name;` and
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST table_name (...)`;     

But it doesn't seem to run..   


It should be right, according to 
[drop table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-table.html) and
[create table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).      

So I don't really know.. but anyways, I found that the order which I create and drop the tables also matters. I put tables that have foreign keys at the end of drop table code, and put them in the beginning of create table codes. It seems to work.